# how to translate pop up windows in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

Is there any way to translate somethings like pop up windows(that are not Node) in java FX ?
for example fade transition , translate transition or any timeline transition .... . 
Thank's

Answer (score 2):

Create a property and use a `Timeline` to "animate" the property. Register a listener with the property and update the window when its value changes.

For example:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TranslateWindowExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button moveButton = new Button("Move");

        moveButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            double currentX = primaryStage.getX() ;
            DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty(currentX);
            x.addListener((obs, oldX, newX) -> primaryStage.setX(newX.doubleValue()));
            KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(x, currentX + 100));
            Timeline animation = new Timeline(keyFrame);
            animation.play();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(moveButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of what do you call popup window ?
For instance, you can create a new stage on the top of your main stage.
You can also use some Tooltip class to add some text over the top of your window.
If you want more classical windows, you should have a look to Alert class.

Anthony